# JavaScript does not work inside PHP loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, loops, while-loop

It seems like when i echo out the result in php, it will loop through the database and display it in the "echo" below but if I try to display it using javascript, it does not even loop. what's the problem in the javascript?

```
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch()){
    $id = $row['id'];

    echo $id; //loops through and displays the all the id's in order in the database
    ?>

    //this only displays the first id and doesn't loop even though it is in the php while loop
    <script>
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<?= $id ?>";
    </script>
    <span id="test"></span>

    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: ID's in html have t be unique. Apart from that the element would have to exists before you can get it by ID.

Comment: @jeroen ok, so is there any other way to "echo" out the variable in javascript besides getElementById and document.write ?

Comment: I don't know why you would want to introduce JS for this rather than directly outputting the HTML, but if you feel you must why not have the PHP output an array of values, and then after the PHP loop have some JS that uses the data in the array to create the appropriate HTML elements?

Comment: There are 100s of ways.  Normally however, you would create the elements with php, and use an echo statement to output them, or use a php if statement to determine when elements or parts of elements are displayed or not.

Comment: ok, the reason i am using javascript is because i have a javascript function that needs to convert the php variable before outputting it.

Comment: Fetch all rows in an array and send them all at once using `var all_data = <?php echo json_encode($your_php_array); ?>;` would be my choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try with this

```
<?php

while($row = $result->fetch()){
$id = $row['id'];

echo $id; //loops through and displays the all the id's in order in the database
?>

//this only displays the first id and doesn't loop even though it is in the php while loop

 <!-- change in id name -->
<span id="test_<?=$id?>"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
   //change here
    document.getElementById("test_<?=$id?>").innerHTML = "<?= $id ?>";
</script>
<?php
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: is there anyway to call a function in this: "document.getElementById("test_<?=$id?>").innerHTML = callJSFunction()" ?

Comment: you should try with click each time you click it will be called.